# how to freeze page to steel drawing graphic?

Tags: c#, graphic

i write a program to drawing a nod in page
but when this process is working page is hanged and when it's ended working page is refreshed and all drawing is cleared !
how can steel page to keep drawing ?

Comment: Are you trying to "steel" the drawing from inside your own process, or from a separate process (.EXE)?

Comment: i not writed program as multi thread and when the processing form is hanged and when it's over every drawing is cleared !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used DoEvents in loop who have high process to prevent freeze program